# null pointer exception occurs when i call a method of showing dialog

Tags: java, android, click

I use AmbilwarnaColorDialog for choosing color.So i included Ambilwarna library. I want to open color dialog by clicking an image. so i just call following method . but it shows me null pointer exception. can anyone help me? 
my code:

```
int color;

 void openDialog(boolean supportsAlpha) {
    AmbilWarnaDialog dialog = new AmbilWarnaDialog(MainActivity.this,
            color, supportsAlpha,
            new AmbilWarnaDialog.OnAmbilWarnaListener() {

                @Override
                public void onOk(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog, int color) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ok",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    MainActivity.this.color = color;
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cancel",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    dialog.show();
}
```

my import is:

```
import yuku.ambilwarna.AmbilWarnaDialog;
```

LogCat is showing like these:

```
01-20 10:54:56.260: E/AndroidRuntime(14407): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-20 10:54:56.260: E/AndroidRuntime(14407): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-20 10:54:56.260: E/AndroidRuntime(14407):    at  yuku.ambilwarna.AmbilWarnaDialog.<init>(AmbilWarnaDialog.java:84)
 01-20 10:54:56.260: E/AndroidRuntime(14407):   at com.example.demofordrawline.MainActivity.openDialog(MainActivity.java:178)
01-20 10:54:56.260: E/AndroidRuntime(14407):    at com.example.demofordrawline.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:251)
01-20 10:54:56.260: E/AndroidRuntime(14407):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4212)
01-20 10:54:56.260: E/AndroidRuntime(14407):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17476)
01-20 10:54:56.260: E/AndroidRuntime(14407):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
01-20 10:54:56.260: E/AndroidRuntime(14407):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
01-20 10:54:56.260: E/AndroidRuntime(14407):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
01-20 10:54:56.260: E/AndroidRuntime(14407):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
01-20 10:54:56.260: E/AndroidRuntime(14407):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 10:54:56.260: E/AndroidRuntime(14407):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-20 10:54:56.260: E/AndroidRuntime(14407):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
01-20 10:54:56.260: E/AndroidRuntime(14407):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
01-20 10:54:56.260: E/AndroidRuntime(14407):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: @VaishaliVaghasiya At which line you are getting error? Your `color` variable is declared globally or in inner method of class?? Are you using  thid party library??

Comment: full doc: https://github.com/yukuku/ambilwarna

Comment: ya i declared color variable globally.

Comment: @VaishaliVaghasiya Can you send me your project demo with library?

Comment: @VaishaliVaghasiya Have you properly checked that your third party library project is imported with green mark and same in workspace too?

Comment: ya i checked it. it is properly imported with green mark.

Comment: Where u are assigning value in color??

Comment: @VaishaliVaghasiya Just check that your color should not be null.

Comment: i am assigning value of color to paint color. but i got error like this so i skips that code now.

Comment: i initialize color like this: int color = 0xffffff00;

Comment: @VaishaliVaghasiya your widget is null in xml assign a default value as stated in the library documentation

Comment: @VaishaliVaghasiya: assign some value to color as color=Color.BLUE then check it

Comment: @VaishaliVaghasiya I think you have commented your color code then you need to assign some value to your color variable and then need to check it.

Comment: i checked by assigning value like color = Color.BLUE, but it is not working. same error.

Comment: @VaishaliVaghasiya  At this line `AmbilWarnaDialog dialog = new AmbilWarnaDialog(MainActivity.this,
            color, supportsAlpha,
            new AmbilWarnaDialog.OnAmbilWarnaListener() {` are you getting NPE?

Comment: ya. you got the point. on that line only i got NPE.

Comment: Is `openDialog()` method is in your `MainActivity` class??

Comment: yes, it is in MainActivity class. and i am calling from onClick method.

Comment: @VaishaliVaghasiya Ok. I have asked you all things which related to it and you have answered it rightly. So can you post here your MainActivity class??

Comment: but i got error at that line only. is there any solution ?

Comment: @VaishaliVaghasiya Yes there is. May be it can't find the class using that library. Have you added jat file for it too?

Comment: ya. jar file is also added properly.

Comment: @VaishaliVaghasiya Then just check in Order and export menu jar file is checked or not??

Comment: i checked. there is all okay.

Comment: @VaishaliVaghasiya Oh. All is okay then can you able to send jar file or your demo project?

Comment: @VaishaliVaghasiya I have completed demo project without using library and all code in one project and working fine now. No any error

Comment: finally i got error. one other xml file of same library is in my layout folder. so it may conflict. thank u all.

Comment: @VaishaliVaghasiya Oh.. finally you got your error and finally i have created a demo. What a mistake :P!!!

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
        package yuku.ambilwarna.demo;

    import yuku.ambilwarna.AmbilWarnaDialog;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class AmbilWarnaDemoActivity extends Activity {
        int color = 0xffffff00;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    openDialog();
                }
            });
        }

        void openDialog() {
            AmbilWarnaDialog dialog = new AmbilWarnaDialog(
                    AmbilWarnaDemoActivity.this, color,
                    new AmbilWarnaDialog.OnAmbilWarnaListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onOk(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog, int color) {

                            AmbilWarnaDemoActivity.this.color = color;
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Color is " + color, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cancel",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
            dialog.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: clean your project then run